# Audio Controls on Lock Screen/Control Center From AV player Issues

Tags: swift3, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

Im new to swift and Im having issues while using MPRemoteCommandCenter.
When I try to control the audio settings, previously accessed songs also start playing along with the current song.
Im trying to access using the following code:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        //Update your button here for the pause command
         self.player!.pause()
        return .success
    }

    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        //Update your button here for the play command
        self.player!.play()
        return .success
    }
```

I have also used the following while ending the view:

```
UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Comment: can you how you're playing songs?

Comment: Im using AVPlayer to play audio

Comment: Are you doing the things mentioned in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49025662/22147

Comment: yes i followed it