# how to play music when tapping the earphone functionality play, previous track, next track

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like some help with implementing these headphone hardware button functionalities with playing music:

1. Double tap: next track
2. Triple tap: previous track
3. Single tap: play/pause

Comment: And what have you tried so far that you need help with?

Comment: Propose closing. duplicate of question asked by OP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024682/how-can-i-control-my-headset-for-my-music-player for which a valid answer was provided. Downvoted

Answer (score 0):

For the number of taps. Implement this code in your viewDidload

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(multipleTap(_:event:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDownRepeat)
}
```

Then create this function:

```
  @objc func multipleTap(_ sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
    let touch: UITouch = event.allTouches!.first!
     if (touch.tapCount == numberOfClicks) {

        // do stuff here

}
```

I hope that helps = )